# How do I search and delete a specific form in my ArrayList

Tags: winforms

I am developing a windows form application that acts as a subscriber for my wcf service. Whenever the publisher publishes a post, my winform will capture the information and add an notification form to an arraylist.

```
public ArrayList notificationList = new ArrayList();
```

And the arguments for my form is as follows

```
public notificationForm(String name, String location, 
                        String imageExtension,String alertType,String memberid,
                        String date,String time,int x,int y,String alertid)
{
    //Codes
}
```

on the notification form, there would be a button called "Clear"
sample code for adding the form to the list is as follows

```
notificationList.Add(new notificationForm("", "", "", "", "", "","", 1, 1,alertId));
```

How do I code the event for the "Clear" button such that it searches the arrayList for a particular (for example) alertID and removes it from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your stuck on using an ArrayList, just walk through it using a ForEach loop till you find the alertID and then call ArrayList.Remove.  I would consider using a Dictionary instead and having the alertID as the key, then you can easily remove it without walking the dictionary.